# Improve performance of runtime-determinded nested for-loops in CUDA

Tags: image-processing, for-loop, cuda

Question: In CUDA, is there a general way of improving the performance of nested for-loops whose conditions are determined at runtime (and therefore can't be unrolled by the compiler)?

Background: I am working on a CUDA implementation of a 2D image filter algorithm. For each pixel of the input the value of the output is calculated by looking at the `(2*r+1) * (2*r+1)` neighbouring pixels. Although `r` is constant for each image, the shape of the filter is dependent on the value at each pixel and hence it can't be converted into a true convolution operation or decomposed into two 1D operations.

I have a fairly efficient implementation for when the filter radius `r` is known at compile time, based on a scatter approach (which is faster than any gather approach I could come up with) where each pixel in the input is assigned a thread. The output is divided into tiles that are kept in shared memory. At the heart of the algorithm is a nested for-loop executed by each thread:

```
for(int i=-r; i<r+1; i++) {
    for(int j=-r; j<r+1; j++) {
        // Calculate and scatter value to output[offsetJ + j][offsetI + i]
    }
}
```

I have generalised the code for `r` given at runtime by using dynamically allocated shared memory. Although the generated result is still correct, execution is between 1.5 to 3 times slower depending on the value of `r`. Through tests I have concluded that the slow-down is due to the runtime determination of the conditions of the above for-loops, meaning the compiler can't unroll the loops which is what I assume is otherwise done.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to improve the performance in this particular case or knows of a similar implementation tips are welcome. My only ideas so far is either to compile different kernels for each value of `r`, or to get rid of the inner loop (but not sure how this would help).

Comment: If know the min value of `r` you could try unroll the loop manually. I'm not sure if an unroll pragma directive would work.

Comment: If there is a relatively small range of possible r values, try making r a template parameter. This makes it a compile ime constant and will sllow loop unrolling. Just instantiate as many versions of the kernel as you need.

Comment: The range for `r` is 1 - 20 (roughly) so manual unrolling might not be an option. I could make it a template but that would create quite a few versions. I'm currently leaning towards versions for `r` of, say, 5, 10, 15 and 20 and padding the filter with zeros for in-between values.

Comment: I don't think there is a better current solution than specialization either using templates or run-time code generation. Please post your suggestion as an answer so we can move this off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gathered from the comments the only options seem to be manual unrolling (which is probably not applicable in this case), the use of templates and runtime code generation. The best option in this particular case, with `r` in the range of 1 - 25 seems to be to create explicit templates for a few different cases and padding in-between values with zeros. Since the complexity grows quadratically with `r`, if all values for `r` are equally common, it seems reasonable to sample the range more densely at the higher end, e.g. create templates for `r` equals 8, 14, 18, 21, 23, and 25.